# Can I create Facebook account from outside the face book website (using facebook API)?

Tags: facebook

Can I create Facebook account from outside the face book website (using facebook API) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Facebook API does not allow for this.

Comment: how can boost likes companies generate millions of fake profiles and likes ?